# Folium 0.11.0 : Keep markers layer in front

Tags: python, layer, markers, folium

I would like to make the markers layer always stay in front, but I can't figure out how to do it.

As soon as I start clicking and unclicking layers in the Layer Control pane, the markers layer disappears behind the choropleth layers.

This is my code:

```
m = folium.Map([40.4165001, -3.7025599], zoom_start=10, tiles='CartoDB Positron', overlay=True)
# folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron', overlay=True).add_to(m)


income=folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=censo,
    data=df1,
    name='Household Income 2016',
    columns=['CDSSCC', 'HouseholdIncome2016'],
    key_on='feature.properties.CDSSCC',
    fill_color='BuGn',
    fill_opacity=1,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    highlight=True,
    legend=False,
).add_to(m)

pop=folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=censo,
    data=df1,
    name='Population 2016',
    columns=['CDSSCC', 'POB_TOTAL'],
    key_on='feature.properties.CDSSCC',
    fill_color='YlOrBr',
    fill_opacity=1,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    highlight=True,
    legend=False,
).add_to(m)

# add clusters to the map
markers_colors = []
for lat, lon, poi, cluster in zip(buildingsmadrid_merged['Latitude'], buildingsmadrid_merged['Longitude'], buildingsmadrid_merged['Name'], buildingsmadrid_merged['Cluster Labels']):
    label = folium.Popup(str(poi) + ' Cluster ' + str(cluster), parse_html=True)
    puntos=folium.CircleMarker(
        [lat, lon],
        radius=5,
        popup=label,
        tooltip = label,
        color='YlOrBr'[cluster-1],
        fill=True,
        fill_color='YlOrBr'[cluster-1],
        fill_opacity=0.7,
        overlay=False).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl(position='topright', collapsed=False, autoZIndex=True).add_to(m)

# m.save(os.path.join('choropleth.html'))

m
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Comment: This notebook contains the whole code. The problem I am referring to is located at the very end, where the final map is created. https://github.com/martabescansa7/Coursera_Capstone/blob/master/CapstoneProject.ipynb  Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folium has a solution for that with the method `m.keep_in_front`.

If you save a list `markers` of the `CircleMarker` objects you can use `m.keep_in_front(*markers)`.
Note that the order of the items will set their priority, last as top most, though I doubt it matters in your case.

---

This solution is currently only working when switching between overlay layers.
In case of switching between base layers this will not work.

I've run into a similar problem when trying to display a tooltip while switching between choropleths.

My setup was a bit different with the choropleth layers having `overlay=False` since I prefer to switch with radio-buttons, and I only had a single layer to keep in front.

I've managed to solve this using these 2 sources:
[A similar question about Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183914/how-to-keep-vector-layer-on-top-of-all-layers-despite-toggling-order)
[This issue from the Folium github](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/86)

Since I switch base layers I've used the [event](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-event) `baselayerchange`.

```
from branca.element import Element

js_keep_in_front = f"""
    {m.get_name()}.on("baselayerchange", function (event) {{
      {popup.get_name()}.bringToFront();
    }});
"""
e = Element(js_keep_in_front)
html = m.get_root()
html.script.get_root().render()
# Insert new element or custom JS
html.script._children[e.get_name()] = e
```

In case there are many objects like in your example, it's possible to group them into a `folium.FeatureGroup` as in [this example](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/FeatureGroup.ipynb) and then keep that single layer in front using the method described.

Note the use of the `get_name` method inside the formatted string. This is important since you don't know the names that folium will use for the map/layers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - that bring to front --> it's only applied at the time of execution. And z offset wasn't working for some unclear reason. Here is some tested code to bring items to the front when there are multiple geojson layers in folium:

```
class Bring2Front(MacroElement):
"""Binds a colormap to a given layer.

Parameters
----------
colormap : branca.colormap.ColorMap
    The colormap to bind.
"""
def __init__(self, fg):
    super(Bring2Front, self).__init__()
    self.fg = fg
    self._template = Template(u"""
    {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
        {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('baselayerchange', function (event) {
            {{this.fg.get_name()}}.bringToFront();
            });
        {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('layeradd', function (event) {
            {{this.fg.get_name()}}.bringToFront();
            });
        {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('layerremove', function (event) {
            {{this.fg.get_name()}}.bringToFront();
            });
    {% endmacro %}
    """)
```

You can then add this macro to bring the feature group forward as follows:

```
m.add_child(Bring2Front(fg))
```